# Apache Camel - Row was updated or deleted by another transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, transactions, apache-camel

I have a batch using camel to consume some records in the database. So the endpoint is a jpa one with a namedQuery.

When I launch the batch I get the exception at the end of the run.
During the run my code updates the entity the endpoint is consuming. My question is how to avoid this exception?

Here is the exception:

```
[03.06.2015 10:47:32,277] WARN  org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log:224 :Consumer Consumer[jpa://ch.gma.nova.vaudoise.entity.ImpactEntity?consumer.namedQuery=mutationsContrat&consumer.parameters=%23params&maximumResults=500] failed polling endpoint: Endpoint[jpa://ch.gma.nova.vaudoise.entity.ImpactEntity?consumer.namedQuery=mutationsContrat&consumer.parameters=%23params&maximumResults=500]. Will try again at next poll. Caused by: [javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException - Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [ch.gma.nova.vaudoise.entity.ImpactEntity#101]]
javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [ch.gma.nova.vaudoise.entity.ImpactEntity#101]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.wrapStaleStateException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1788) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1705) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaConsumer$1.doInTransaction(JpaConsumer.java:90) ~[camel-jpa-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaConsumer.poll(JpaConsumer.java:80) ~[camel-jpa-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:187) [camel-core-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:114) [camel-core-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:482) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:315) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:193) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:308) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1176) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:795) [na:1.7.0]
```

And the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IMPACT_FLUX")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = ImpactEntity.NAMED_QUERY_MUTATION, query = "Select i from ImpactEntity i where i.process = 'MUTATION_CONTRAT' and i.status = :status and i.application = :application"),
    @NamedQuery(name = ImpactEntity.NAMED_QUERY_ANNONCE_SINISTRE, query = "Select i from ImpactEntity i where i.process = 'ANNONCE_SINISTRE' and i.status = :status and i.application = :application"), })
public class ImpactEntity {

  public static final String NAMED_QUERY_MUTATION = "mutationsContrat";

  public static final String NAMED_QUERY_ANNONCE_SINISTRE = "annonceSinistre";

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "seqImpactFlux")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "seqImpactFlux", sequenceName = "SEQ_IMPACT_FLUX")
  @Column(name = "ID_IMPACT")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "ID_CONTRAT")
  private Long numContrat;

  @Column(name = "ID_ANCIEN_CONTRAT")
  private Long numAncienContrat;

  @Column(name = "ID_PARTENAIRE")
  private Long numPartenaire;

  @Column(name = "ID_PRESTATION")
  private Long numPrestation;

  @Column(name = "STATUS")
  private String status;

  @Column(name = "PROCESSUS")
  private String process;

  @Column(name = "APPLICATION")
  private String application;

  @Column(name = "CODE")
  private String code;

  @Version
  @Column(name = "OPTLOCK")
  private Integer version;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID_SUIVI")
  private SuiviMessageEntity suiviMessage;

  @Column(name = "DT_CREATION")
  private Date dateCreation;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this issue because two concurrent threads update the same entity and the [optimistic locking mechanism](http://vladmihalcea.com/preventing-lost-updates-in-long-conversations/) prevents [losing updates](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-database-locking-and-the-lost-update-phenomena/).

There are several ways to fix this issue:

- If the two transactions update different parts of the `ImpactEntity` you have two options:

  1. You can use [version-less optimistic locking](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-downside-of-version-less-optimistic-locking/)
  2. You use [DML UPDATE](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html#d5e1152) to bypass the version checking
- If the two transactions update the same field of the `ImpactEntity` you need to use [pessimistic locking](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-locking-patterns-how-do-pessimistic_read-and-pessimistic_write-work/) in both transactions, so once one transaction acquires the row-level lock, the other transaction will wait for the lock to be released

  ```
  ImpactEntity impactEntity = ...
  session.buildLockRequest(new LockOptions(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE))
     .lock(impactEntity);
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer a few days ago.
I tried this in my dao:
    `public void save(ImpactEntity impact) {  
        LOG.debug("save", "Sauvegarde de l'impact " + impact);
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().buildLockRequest(new     LockOptions(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)).lock(impact);
    getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(impact);
    getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().flush();
  }`
Do I need to do something else to release the lock?

Comment: The lock is only released when the transaction commits or rolls back

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your batch job instances are interleaving with each other, so they read and update the same data.

Maybe you are using a fixed rate (default) for the JPA component, so another job instance starts before the previous one has finished.

To solve the issue, you should probably use [fixed delay](http://camel.apache.org/jpa.html):

```
consumer.useFixedDelay=true
```

Comment: Could you post your route configuration for the JPA component which includes this flag?

Comment: My route was like this: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PROTOCOLE_JPA).append(ImpactEntity.class.getName())
      .append("?consumer.useFixedDelay=true&consumer.namedQuery=").append(namedQuery).append("&consumer.parameters=#params");
    if (nbMessagesMax != null) {
      sb.append("&maximumResults=").append(nbMessagesMax);
    }
    from(sb.toString()).process(new SendEventOfObjectProcessor(process)).to(BATCHCORE_INJECTOR);`

Sorry but I don't know how to format in the comments...